# Formula problem

Tags: subscripts

I am using https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

And added my latex as follows:

```
 \begin{equation}
 SSIM(x,y)=\frac{{\left ( 2 \mu_x\mu_y+ C_1 \right )+ \left (2 \sigma _x_y+C_2\right)}} 
{\left(\mu_x^2+\mu_y^2+C_1)(\sigma_x^2+\sigma_y^2+C_2\right)}
  \label{eq:SSMI}
\end{equation}
```

I expected the following formula but instead of I got the error:!Double subscript. ...y+C_1\right)+ ...

[image]

Comment: `\sigma _x_y` -> `\sigma_{xy}`.

Comment: in addition to the subscript error, you should remove the `\left` and `\right` which are not wanted here

Comment: Also, in the numerator, there should be no "+" -- it should be a multiplication for SSIM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Double subscripts are not allowed by TeX, you should replace `\sigma_x_y` by `\sigma_{xy}`.

Also, it is preferable to use a specific operator name for such a function.

Edit: And as David Carlisle pointed out, the `\left` and `\right` commands are of no use here. It can only add unwanted additional spacing.

You can try something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\SSIM}{SSIM}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \SSIM(x,y) = \frac{(2\mu_x\mu_y + C_1) + (2 \sigma _{xy} + C_2)} 
    {(\mu_x^2 + \mu_y^2+C_1) (\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2+C_2)}
  \label{eq:SSMI}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To achieve the desired output, simply replace `\sigma _x_y`  by `\sigma _{xy}`.

Comment: Please make your answer self-contained, see [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I am thankfull to all. I try to rewrite with \DeclareMathOperator it didnt work :( What is the purpose of using it? For example after declared the formula may I call it just writing SSMI etc?

Comment: Errors: Can be used only in preamble.... undefined control sequence declaremath and SSIM

Comment: @user8151324 You have to load the `amsmath` package or its extension `mathtools`, as I did, to use the `DeclareMathOperator` command. It is a typographical convention that math operators should be typesetted in roman type, like the main text, hence this command. See the `amsmath` documentation for more information.

Comment: I have all: \usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}

Comment: Loading `amsmath` should be enough for this. Since my piece of code works perfectly with either `amsmath` or `mathtools` loaded in the preamble, it seems that your problem comes from somewhere else. Maybe you should start by trying to reduce the number of packages to the strict minimum.